# MemTest86+ fails to start after GRUB screen

Tags: boot, grub, memtest86+

I'm trying to run a memory test on Intel NUC with Celeron® N5105 CPU. The PC hardware is sound, runs `mprime` and `linpack` on Ubuntu 22.04.1 error free. Other utilities boot fine from USB drive, only MemTest86+ v6.0 and v6.01 give me problems. They UEFI boot to the GRUB screen and go to blank screen after any of 3 selections offered is taken. What could be the problem? Celeron® N5105 CPU? I have a single 8GB SODIMM installed.

Needless to say, the same USB sticks (I tried several), run just fine in other PCs.

---

The plot thickens. I was trying different USB ports on the NUC and a few times MemTest86+ started (version without GRUB). Unfortunately, this is not repeatable. Secondly, I'm running `memtester` on Ubuntu for hours already, without any errors.

---

Updated the original BIOS Version 0029 - ATJSPCPX.0029.2021.1117.1857 to the newest Version 0038 - ATJSLCPX.0038.2022.1114.1802 and ...

it works. There is *Fixed Boot issues* line item in Release Notes.

Comment: Any chance this is because the memory is faulty?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? You can tell by if Legacy or CSM is enabled or disabled.

Comment: @John No. Mprime or linpack would fail. MemTest would at least load and start running.

Comment: @Ramhound UEFI boot.